# laravel page is loading too slow (30s)

Tags: php, performance, caching, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($grupAll as $grup)

@if($grup->urun_kodu == '01010101')
<label>
<div class="user-panel">
   <div class="pull-left image">
      <input type="checkbox" name="veri[]" class="flat-red" value="{{$grup->id}}" >
         <img src="{{ asset($grup->urun_resim) }}" class="img-circle"
         alt="User Image" title="{{$grup->urun_aciklamasi}}"/>{{$grup->urun_adi}}

   </div>
</div>
</label>
@endforeach
```

I have sixty 'urun_kodu' and I use this 'foreach' many times. So the page is loading very slowly. Is there any solution in laravel cache all page or something ?

Comment: And ı m very new at database and laravel and English :)

Comment: ematoengineering.com/question/product.txt 
 
ematoengineering.com/question/partofcontroller.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 100% sure this is not the reason of your slowness. The foreach loop is for sure taking a lot less than 1 second. Please provide more information on what else you are doing in the controller / template.

Comment: I m using this foreach so much

Comment: Check if these are fast: `$contacts = Customers::where('gSirket',$users->name)->get();`
`$urunler = Product::all();`

Perhaps you have problems with your database connection.

Comment: I checked them. These are fast.

Comment: Do u have any other solution idea for my question ?